# is there any Birt web portal(open source) similar to cognos connection

Tags: birt, cognos-bi

I am looking for something like where user can login to run/view  reports, schedule them etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [Pentaho](http://pentaho.com), if you need a full BI platform allowing to display BIRT reports. Another easier option is to use a generalist open source portal such [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com), and display BIRT reports within using one of the following:

- a portlet report viewer such [Visioneo](http://www.visioneo.org) (embedded and making use of portal security to run reports)
- Eclipse BIRT WebViewer through iframes (you have to handle report security yourself, for example by encrypting parameter values)
- BIRT viewer toolkit through javascript API (you have to handle report security yourself, for example by encrypting parameter values)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one: http://tradui.de/web/produkte/birt-reportserver-servbird.jsf
It provides some nice features to integrate or directly implement into your server and application infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free scheduling and server platform called BIRT iHub F-Type. You can download the Windows, Linux or VMWare image at http://www.actuate.com/resources/product-downloads/.